# How to understand the backpressure status shown on the UI

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.10, I have a simple flink application,

1. Read data from Kafka
2. Process data(simple one-to-one map)
3. Sink to DB

When I look at the backpressure status on the UI, it shows:

```
Operator BackPresure
Source   High
Map      High
Sink     OK
```

I would ask, given the above backpressure status, which part is the bottleneck? I think sink operator is the bottleneck, which is writing to DB, but I don't understand why its BackPresure status is `OK`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the Sink is probably the limiting factor in your program, and the one causing the backpressure.

In 1.13/1.14 they changed the terminology: the Backpressure UI has beeen revamped; and instead of talking about 'Backpressure' for an operator, they talk about it being 'Backpressure**d**' or its 'Backpressure status'.

In your case the Sink would not be backpressured (no sink can ever be, by definition), but the Source and Map operators would be.

The new version also adds a new concept of Idleness (determined by whether or not there is input available) in addition to Backpressure (measured in availability of output buffers). This would IMHO help in figuring out if its the network IO or the CPU being the limiting factor for a program.

Here is what it looks like:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/monitoring/back_pressure/